# Unity Multiplayer Photon Engine Game on WebGL not connecting to remote computers

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, multiplayer, photon, photon-pun

I have a multiplayer game (Shooter Sports) which I recently posted on itch.io. I made the game using Unity and Photon Engine (for the multiplayer aspect). However, when testing the game after publishing it, I find that I am unable to connect and play games against players on other remote computers.

I have done some testing, and I know that my standalone version of the game can connect perfectly well to other computers. I also know that the WebGL version (that I uploaded to itch.io) works locally on my computer, and it even works if I use two different browsers on the same computer.

Everything I try does not work. Help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.